# Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, android, gradle

Good Day, I can't build my project, there was and error like: "The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64k"

and I have tried to implement MultiDex enabled, but there is another exception...

Message From Gradle Build:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Error:UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Error:  at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
Error:  at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:191)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:279)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:569)
Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:366)
Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)
Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
Error:  at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 3 mins 45.026 secs
```

My `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    /* Android */
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'


    /* Libraries */


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have added name tag in manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".application.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

And MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication. Why I can't build my project ?

What was wrong ?

Comment: Is instarun enabled?

Comment: Like suggested below, do a clean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this line in your gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1563M
```

Then clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: The_Martian can you explain a little about this please?

Comment: Where is `gradle.properties`? I can only find `gradle-wrapper.properties`

Answer (score -3):

The solution for the above issue :

Clean and Rebuild your Project. Its working fine for me